# For some reason the words sinchservice and the names of activity's have an error saying cannot resolve error 'CallActivity'?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason the words sinchservice and the names of activity's have an error saying cannot resolve error 'CallActivity'?

In addition on the android maifest it says:

Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared

Code in android manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    package="com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.video"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1"

    <uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"
        android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />




    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <service android:name=".SinchService" />


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CallScreenActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".IncomingCallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".PlaceCallActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thankyou

App file:https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling/archive/master.zip

Comment: Missing `>` in `<manifest` tag

Comment: I mean use `android:versionCode="1" >` instead of `android:versionCode="1"` then build your project